# Interesting examples of spaces ideal for studying fundamental groups and (co)homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Usually, when we study algebraic topology, we learn a lot of theory with just a few examples, like compact surfaces (orientable or not), wedge product of many circles, and a combination of those.

Are these any slightly more complicated but special examples which shows important facts about the truth/falsity of some interesting statements? I find that I need to know more examples, but I do not know where to start. Some reference would be helpful.

To be more focused, I am mostly interested in just singular homology and spaces with "low dimensions".

To give an example of something which is more specific, for instance, examples of spaces with homology different from the examples above would be interesting.

Comment: Could you give some examples of these "interesting statements"? Currently your question is very broad, and I can't see how I could feel confident that any answer I might write will be useful to you.

Comment: Your "Usually" statement seems unjustified to me. Pick up some several books on algebraic topology. Page through them. You'll see lots of examples. And you should expand the collection of spaces you are interested in: real projective spaces $\mathbb R P^n$; complex projective spaces $\mathbb CP^n$; CW complexes in general, ...

Comment: @KennyWong I understand your point, but the thing is, I do not know many examples of specific things which are interesting. I have tried to describe what I mean by adding to the question. This is going to be broad because if I can be specific, I won't need to ask.

Comment: What *is* interesting to you? Are you interested in smooth manifolds, vector bundles and differential forms? Or do you want to study (co)homology theories for the fun of it (something like "how do $H(-,\Bbb Z)$ and $\pi_\ast$ compare?")? I think the question is still too broad.